# Reading JSON Object Value in C# code

Tags: c#, json, parsing, json.net, azure-machine-learning-service

Folks,
I am trying to access a json value from Azure ML rest service but i get a null value all the time, i tried different options but it did not work. Can u please provide ideas.

*Json String*

```
{
    "Results": {
        "output1": {
            "type": "table",
            "value": {
                "ColumnNames": ["Sentiment",
                "Score"],
                "ColumnTypes": ["String",
                "Double"],
                "Values": [["negative",
                "0.20"],
                **["negative",
                "0.03"]**]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Trying to fetch the value between **

Tried the below.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
JObject o = JObject.Parse(sentimentvalue);
string valv = (string)o.SelectToken("Results[0].output1[0].Values[0]");
```

Comment: You should provide a correct JPath for SelectToken

Comment: You can deserialize with the following function...
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject

Comment: JObject.Parse(json)["Results"]["output1"]["value"]["Values"]

Comment: This worked for me: `string valv = (string)o.SelectToken("Results.output1.value.Values[0]");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON path in the SelectToken seems to be wrong. 
Try this:

```
string valv = (string)o.SelectToken("$.Results.output1.value.Values[0][1]");
```

Comment: Thanks but how do i specifically access the below values. Now my consoleout looks like this
 ["negative","0.03"]

Comment: I think i found it..
  string valv = (string)o.SelectToken("$.Results.output1.value.Values[0][1]").ToString();

Comment: @xtechkid thanks mate!